# What are the parameters for saving a phone number field in Apex?

Tags: apex, insert, phone

When I insert the Order record, the Order saves but the custom phone number field does not. What are the parameters for saving a phone number field in Apex?

```
Order o = new Order(AccountId = a.Id, OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(), Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
            ShipToContactId = c.Id,
            Status = 'Active',
            EffectiveDate = Date.newInstance(DateTime.now().year(),DateTime.now().month(),DateTime.now().day()),
            Requested_Delivery_Date__c = Date.newInstance(DateTime.now().year(),DateTime.now().month(),DateTime.now().day() + 1),
            Date_Fulfilled__c = Date.newInstance(DateTime.now().year(),DateTime.now().month(),DateTime.now().day() + 1),
            Ship_to_Phone__c = '2345678901'
    );
    system.debug(o.Ship_to_Phone__c);
    insert o;
    system.debug(o.Ship_to_Phone__c);
    o = [SELECT Id, ShipToContact.LastName, Ship_to_Phone__c FROM Order WHERE ShipToContact.LastName = 's********' LIMIT 1];
    system.debug(o);
```

Comment: Please edit your question with minimal code illustrating the problem, that is always useful to get a more precise answer.

Comment: @Raul cool, that is good to go

Comment: Code looks alright, just to rule out possibility that you may be looking at different data, Is it possible that you have multiple records for result that is returned via soql? If you use same data and create record from Salesforce UI do you see same behavior?

Comment: they're the same object with the same SF ID

Comment: Is this same behavior when you insert an order from Ui?

Comment: yes, the record saves but the phone field doesn't save

Comment: Do you have other automation that could be clearing this value? E.g. a second trigger, a flow or process builder?

Comment: Also, what context is this code running in? Does the user have appropriate permissions for reading and writing the field?

Comment: In the "Where is this Used" you can see it's not used in any automation that is updating it on create. The user does have write permissions for the object and field. I am able to save it after creating, so I guess it works, but not sure why.

Comment: Look at debug logs when you insert the record, might give some more clue

Answer (score -1):

Maybe trying using this way work

```
Order o = new Order();
o.AccountId = a.Id;
o.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
o.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
o.ShipToContactId = c.Id;
o.Status = 'Active';
o.EffectiveDate = Date.newInstance(DateTime.now().year(),DateTime.now().month(),DateTime.now().day());
o.Requested_Delivery_Date__c = Date.newInstance(DateTime.now().year(),DateTime.now().month(),DateTime.now().day()+ 1);
o.Date_Fulfilled__c = Date.newInstance(DateTime.now().year(),DateTime.now().month(),DateTime.now().day()+ 1);
o.Ship_to_Phone__c = '2345678901';   

system.debug(o.Ship_to_Phone__c);
insert o;
system.debug(o.Ship_to_Phone__c);
o = [SELECT Id, ShipToContact.LastName, Ship_to_Phone__c FROM Order WHERE ShipToContact.LastName = 's********' LIMIT 1];
system.debug(o);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).